# How can i disable Jupyter as VS Code's default Python executor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Jupyter kernel is slow to load and I don't need code cells in VS Code (they're poorly formatted anyways, and just awkward). Is there any way to disable Jupyter kernel as the executor and just go back to using ipython in the attached VS Code terminal?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
"python.dataScience.sendSelectionToInteractiveWindow": false
```

You can make it directly on settings.json file or through settings tab: *Python > Data Science: Send Selection To Interactive Window*.

You can make it at user or at workspace level.

Comment: Does the above disable the extension ?  I do not have the "Python > Data Science: "

Comment: It doesn't do anything, I got here and my flag was already set to false.

I'm luckily not using python right now so I had to disable the Python extension to disable the Jupyter extension, but it stays part of the IDE, still breaking.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112791