# Visual studio code - disable jupyter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have problem with my VSC, when i hit Shift+Enter it execute selected line in Ipython, however when i hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER it starts jupyter notebook and execute whole file.

Is is possible to disable jupyter notebook ? Is is possible to make "CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER" to execute whole file in Ipython?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55466742/how-can-i-disable-jupyter-as-vs-codes-default-python-executor

Comment: I saw that post, sadly its not working for me. Even if i display it still starts jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

Drac0. If you want to take a look at the keybindings for the python extension first open up the keyboard shortcuts window in VSCode (Ctrl-Shift-P for the command palette then pick Perferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts). Then in that window type Python to see the current keybindings. Any commands that talk about Python Interactive Window refer to the Jupyter interface, while any Terminal commands refer to the standard terminal. You can change any of the keybindings here to how you want them.

Answer (score -1):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> → Open Keyboard Shortcuts.
2. Type `jupyter`.
3. Remove the keybinding.

Comment: You should provide an explanation on how exactly your answer is better than the @j-k 's comment, pointing to a duplicate answer/question on StackOverflow.